# Error on yarn install in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg

I pulled a ruby on rails repo from github. On entering rails s it asks me "Your Yarn packages are out of date. Please run yarn install"
On running yarn install I get following error:-

```
error An unexpected error occurred: 
"/home/umesh/Downloads/dms/dms_webapp/node_modules/node: Command 
failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c node installArchSpecificPackage
Directory: /home/umang/Downloads/dms/dms_webapp/node_modules/node
Output:
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'
```

Comment: And did you ran `yarn install`?

Comment: Yes I got the above error on yarn install

Comment: Have you checked you have the node-gyp module?, you could try removing it and reinstalling again if something has been corrupted during the yarn install command.

Comment: How do I remove this module?

Comment: you can try one thing, delete all the node_modules which are get installed in your project directory, and again try to install yarn.